# How to use OR operator in strings with PHP

Tags: php, operators

Brand new to php and I want to say "if dc is equal to ABC or DEF. In php, is it:
    if ($dc == "ABC"|"DEF")

Comment: It's more like _if dc is equal to ABC or dc is equal to DEF_

Comment: if ($dc == "ABC" || $dc == "DEF"), but you also may use in_array as suggested below.
You could search for it, you could find so many good options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in_array.

```
if(in_array($dc, ["ABC", "DEF"])){
    // One of them is  in $dc
}
```

In_array returns true if the needle ($dc) is found in the array.